# Custom iOS lock app

Tags: ios, locking, app-store, jailbreak

I'm looking to write a custom lock app to replace the default PIN lock on iOS.

As there are no apps like this available on the App Store currently, its clear that either Apple rejects these types of apps or its just not possible with the currently available APIs.

The app is just for personal use, but I'd just like to know if it's possible before starting. Anyone know which is the case?

Thanks

Comment: What feature would your custom lock app have that the built-in one doesn't?

Comment: I'm going to keep that one under the rug on the off, off chance that Apple ever allows apps of this nature on the App Store :P

Comment: @Z.O. I assure you they never will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace the standard lock screen or PIN entry keyboard EXCEPT on jailbroken devices.  First, there's no way to do it with the official SDK.  Secondly even if there was Apple would not allow you to modify any of the system applications.  If you're serious about doing it though for "personal use" and are OK with voiding your warranty (and/or possibly bricking your device) you could look into jailbreaking and the tools available.  A hint in the right direction would be to learn as much as you can about SpringBoard and mobile substrate.  Hope that helps.

Comment: "EXCEPT on jailbroken devices. First, there's no way to do it with the **official SDK**" This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the current APIs. As soon as someone pushes the home button your app will be sent to the background or terminated depending on how it is configured.

Comment: you can allow an app to run persistently in the background if it uses location tracking I believe? You can also request the run in background and only terminate when receiving low memory warning or manually terminated. Correct me if I'm wrong about this

Comment: Yes, I did say you can run in the background "depending on how [the app] is configured", for example, if you are location tracking, doing Voice over  IP or playing background audio. But none of this helps trying to implement a lock screen; background apps do not have control of the screen, so a user can trivially switch away from your app.